# How to use document.createElement() without defining a variable

Tags: javascript, createelement

I'm pretty sure I already know the answer to this but I kind of would like an explanation.

I want to create and append an element without having to define it in a variable (it seems like such a waste to me and is unnecessary).

```
var errorMessage = document.getElementById("errorMessage");

 errorMessage.innerHTML = "";

errorMessage.appendChild(document.createElement('p').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Due to an egg allergy, your child will NOT receive the flu vaccine.")));
```

So this actually appends the text node into the errorMessage element, but will not generate the 'p' tag.

I just think its ridiculous that you have to define a variable to create a new element when it's much more elegant this way. I haven't been able to find anything online about this. Does anyone know a way for this to work the way I'd like or possibly know why it won't work this way?

Comment: In practice, creating a variable is just visual annoying. In the assembler will exist a variable, there is no waste. Somewhere has to go the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`appendChild` returns the appended child. So I think you want

```
var text = "Due to an egg allergy, your child will NOT receive the flu vaccine.";
document.getElementById("errorMessage")
  .appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
  .appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
```

Comment: @squint You can still put `errorMessage.innerHTML = "";` before this code.

Comment: @Xufox: Part of the question is about not having to create a variable.

Comment: @squint Wasn’t this meant for the `p` tag?

Comment: @squint I think the question is about not storing `document.createElement('p')` in a variable, but `errorMessage` can be stored.

Comment: @Xufox, Oriol: Looking at the question again, I think you're right. I misunderstood the issue. +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to simply set the HTML of the `errorMessage` element to some HTML, why not just using the `innerHTML` property?

```
errorMessage.innerHTML = '<p>Due to an egg allergy, your child will NOT receive the flu vaccine.</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's something you do more than once, create an abstraction

```
function createP(text) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  return p;
}

document.body.appendChild(createP('hello world'));
```