# Access ViewChild i:e element Reference of a dynamically created Element in Angular?

Tags: angular, viewchild

I am Creating a iframe Dynamically in Angular in ngOninit.

```
  ngOnInit(){
      const el = document.createElement('iframe');
      el.setAttribute('sandbox', '');
    }
```

And then using ElementRef in ngAfterViewInit i am trying to access the dynamically created component.

```
this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('iframe');
```

But if gives me null always , how to get the reference of the element here, i even tried with afterContentInit nothing works.

Comment: Try to wrap this call into `setTimeout` with 1 sec delay, if it works, you should be able to keep this call inside empty `setTimeout`.

Comment: i did try using SetTimeout also dosent work @CommercialSuicide

Comment: In provided code i see, that you create element and set attribute, but do you include this element to DOM? Do you see this iframe in inspector?

Comment: Yes it get added to the DOM i can see it in my browser window

Comment: You need to attach `el` to something in the component's template, e.g `const outerDiv = this.elRef.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];` then `outerDiv.appendChild(el);`

Comment: @eric99 i can see the iframe but i cannot access it after view init

Comment: I think `document.createElement()` puts it on the DOM (therefore you can see it), but it is outside of the elRef - so I suggest appending it to something in your Angular template.

Comment: @eric99 yes i think you are right but using this creates 2 iframes in the view i donot know why ?

Comment: Instead of `outerDiv.appendChild(el);` try `outerDiv.createElement('iframe');`

Comment: it says create element is not a function

Comment: I think we are on the right track. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847752/how-to-use-document-createelement-without-defining-a-variable) and see if you can make use of the examples. I'll take a further look later on.